# Create Journal Entry using V3 API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How can you insert a general Journal Entry using V3 API? In V2, there was the JournalEntry object, but I don't see one in the V3 docs or the rollout schedule.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish: when an invoice is created in our system, we're making the appropriate create call that includes the invoice header and lines. At the same time, we need to make 0 or more journal entries related to each line. These are not the standard journal entries which QB automatically makes for invoices, but instead future revenue recognition entries related to each line. The recognition calculations take place in our app and if there are journal entries, the data needs to be sent to QB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not available in V3 yet. It is not part of coming OCT release also.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Release notification will be made in the blog. 
Blog - https://developer.intuit.com/blog

Thanks